# javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root value already specified

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using `SceneBuilder` for JavaFX pages and NetBeans for the java code including the controller code.  I've got several controllers all of which load and one mains section of code that loads the JavaFX pages. They all work, except for 1 page.

Here is a code spinet of a method that loads a page just fine:

```
public boolean showAddProductDialog() 
{
    try 
    {
        // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup dialog.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

        loader.setLocation(FXMLInventoryWizard.class.getResource("AddProductScreen.fxml"));

        AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        System.out.println("page identifier points to loader.load  line 227");
        // Give the controller access to the main app.
       AddProductController controller = loader.getController();


        controller.setFXMLInventoryWizard(this);

        // Create the dialog Stage.
        Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
        dialogStage.setTitle("Add Product");
        dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        dialogStage.setScene(scene);

        // Set the person into the controller.
        AddProductController controller1= loader.getController();
        controller1.setDialogStage(dialogStage);
        controller1.setFXMLInventoryWizard(this);
        // Show the dialog and wait until the user closes it
        dialogStage.showAndWait();

       // return controller.isOkClicked();
       return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("there was an IO Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

Here's a code snipet of the one that doesn't load:

public boolean showModifyProductDialog() 
{
    try 
    {
        // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup dialog.
        FXMLLoader loader1 = new FXMLLoader();
        System.out.println("we instantiated a FXMLLoader");
        //  loader1.setRoot(ModifyProductController.ModProdPageAnchorPane);
        loader1.setLocation(FXMLInventoryWizard.class.getResource("ModifyProductScreen.fxml"));
        System.out.println("loader.load is " + loader1.load().toString());
        AnchorPane page1 = (AnchorPane) loader1.load();
        System.out.println("did page get assigned to loader.load?");
        // Give the controller access to the main app.
        ModifyProductController controller = loader1.getController();
        controller.setFXMLInventoryWizard(this);

        // Create the dialog Stage.
        Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
        dialogStage.setTitle("Modify Product");
        dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        Scene scene = new Scene(page1);
        dialogStage.setScene(scene);

        // Set the person into the controller.
        ModifyProductController controller1= loader1.getController();
        controller1.setDialogStage(dialogStage);
        controller1.setFXMLInventoryWizard(this);
        // Show the dialog and wait until the user closes it
        dialogStage.showAndWait();

       // return controller.isOkClicked();
       return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's the stack trace including a few lines (before the stack trace) of my own debugging code:

```
in handleModifyProduct method of main page controller
we instantiated a FXMLLoader
in the constructor of ModifyProducttController
in the initialize method of ModifyProductContoller
loader.load is AnchorPane[id=AnchorPane]
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root value already specified.
file:/C:/Users/altered-chords/Desktop/FXMLInventoryWizard/dist/run164609179/FXMLInventoryWizard.jar!/fxmlinventorywizard/ModifyProductScreen.fxml
file:/C:/Users/altered-chords/Desktop/FXMLInventoryWizard/dist/run164609179/FXMLInventoryWizard.jar!/fxmlinventorywizard/ModifyProductScreen.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.createElement(FXMLLoader.java:2755)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2704)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at fxmlinventorywizard.FXMLInventoryWizard.showModifyProductDialog(FXMLInventoryWizard.java:268)
    at fxmlinventorywizard.FXMLDocumentController.handleModifyProduct(FXMLDocumentController.java:269)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You cannot load a new fxml with a fxml loader instance where the root is already assigned unless the root element of the fxml is a `<fx:root>` element. Otherwise fxmlloader knows something went wrong. Since you'd need 2 different root elements... `FXMLLoader` is supposed to be one-use only BTW, so you should not do `System.out.println(loader.load()); x = loader.load();` (the second `load` call could be replaced with a call to `getRoot()`).

Answer (score 0):

I went over the code with a flea comb.  compared both snipets line by line.  For the 4th time copied the working code into the non-working section and made the edits.  This time it worked.  It seems like my architecture is lacking though.  Too much identical code.  I have alot to learn.  Thanks all.